# JxBrowser related

Tags: java, swing, browser, jxbrowser

I am trying to create a browser app with JxBrowser. I have imported all the jar files in my project but it still throws an error for the statement

```
import com.teamdev.jxbrowser.chromium.BrowserContext;
```

and further on for

```
Browser browser = BrowserFactory.createBrowser(BrowserType.Mozilla);

frame.add(browser.getComponent(), BorderLayout.CENTER);

browser.navigate("http://www.google.com");
```

I am running this code on a MAC OS X and have the appropriate jar file imported as well. 
Can someone help me with this

Comment: What errors?  How you compile the code? What IDE are you using (if any)?

Comment: The version of JxBrowser that i am using is version 5.0 and i have the jar files downloaded for the same. but the jar file has the BrowserFactory class missing in the classes under that particular jar. Hence it is not able to compile code and not allowing me to use BrowserFactory.create()

Answer (score 0):

I suppose you use one of the latest JxBrowser versions. Probably 4.x. In this case please note that public [API](http://jxbrowser-support.teamdev.com/samples) in 4.x has been changed. Now, to create `Browser` instance you need to use the following way:

```
import com.teamdev.jxbrowser.chromium.Browser;
import com.teamdev.jxbrowser.chromium.swing.BrowserView;

import javax.swing.*;
import java.awt.*;

/**
 * This sample demonstrates how to create Browser instance,
 * embed it into Swing BrowserView container, display it in JFrame and
 * navigate to the "www.google.com" web site.
 */
public class BrowserSample {
    public static void main(String[] args) {
        Browser browser = new Browser();
        BrowserView browserView = new BrowserView(browser);

        JFrame frame = new JFrame();
        frame.setDefaultCloseOperation(WindowConstants.EXIT_ON_CLOSE);
        frame.add(browserView, BorderLayout.CENTER);
        frame.setSize(700, 500);
        frame.setLocationRelativeTo(null);
        frame.setVisible(true);

        browser.loadURL("http://www.google.com");
    }
}
```